# Adding custom JS (Slick Slider) to Magento Custom Theme without overriding parent

Tags: magento2, requirejs, custom-theme, requirejs-config.js

I created a custom theme which is inheriting from the blank theme.
Now I wanted to integrate Slick and found this article which I followed 
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-slick-carousel/

**My problem:**
I pasted this to a freshly created `app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/_YOUR_THEME_/web/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        slick:        'js/slick'
    },
    shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Now when I check the file on the web page this is the only content in it, of course because it's obviously overriding the file from the parent theme

I could copy paste the content of the parent theme's `requirejs-config.js`
but then still if the parent theme gets updated I will not get those updates.

How can I just extend the file instead of overriding?
Or is there a better way to integrate the js library?

Comment: what is the issue bro?

Comment: The issue is what I posted in my question.
What's not clear? Can you be more specific?
When I create a requirejs-config the way I described then it obviously overrides the requirejs-config which is inherited from the parent. I dont want that to happen. I want to keep the contents of the original requirejs-config and extend it with my custom requirejs-config

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like using this path

`app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/_YOUR_THEME_/requirejs-config.js`

instead of

`app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/_YOUR_THEME_/web/requirejs-config.js`

placing the file in the theme root instead of the web subfolder, solves my issue.

Maybe someone can give me some insight on why this is the case, and why or under what circumstances you would want to follow the Inchoo tutorial and put the file in the web subfolder then.

But for now this seems to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right!